# Finding $k$ such that $\frac{3x^2+kx-44}{x^2-121}$ simplifies to $\frac{3x-4}{x-11}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If the rational expression $\frac{3x^2+kx-44}{x^2-121}$, where $k$ is an element of $\mathbb{W}$, simplifies to $\frac{3x-4}{x-11}$, then the value of $k$ must be?

my work:

$$\frac{3x^2+kx-44}{x^2-121}= \frac{3x-4}{x-11}$$
so the answer = value of $k$ is $11$.

Comment: Please use mathjax to typeset your equations. Or, at the very least, use parentheses. What you wrote is $3x - \frac{4}{x} - 11$, which is not what you intended.

Comment: Notice $x^2-121=(x+11)(x-11)$

Comment: @Ranveer Masuta please don't change a **better version (MathJax-ed Version)** of the question. And welcome to MSE.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If $$\frac{3x^2+kx-44}{x^2-121}=\frac{3x-4}{x-11}$$

Then, with $ x=1$, we get

$$\frac{3+k-44}{1-121}=\frac{1}{10}$$

and

$$k=-12+41=29$$

Comment: so the value of k is 28?

Comment: i thought it was 11

Comment: @RanveerMasuta You can check it is not 11.

Comment: $-11$ is not a root of this polynomial.

Comment: it is 29 the value of k

Comment: it should be 12 where you wrote 13?

Comment: @PAM1499 Yes, thanks.

Comment: how did you get the value of k equaling to 28

Comment: Thats ok.... ;)

Comment: @RanveerMasuta I edited, it is 29.

Comment: I had another question ,Well i solved it heres the question: The area is square units of a rectangle can be represented by the expression 12x^(2)+25x-7,and it's length can be represented by (3x+7). Determine the value of "x" if the perimeter of the rectangle is 68 units.

Comment: my answer was as follows:Let's say the width is in the form (ax+b). From the -7 in the area, I can guess b=-1 since the b would multiply with the +7 to equal -7. From the 12 in 12x², since the length is 3x, the a I can guess to equal 4x, so the width theorize is expressed by 4x-1.

Now the perimeter of a rectangle equals 2•(length + width)=68, or length+width=34=(3x+7)+(4x-1)=7x+6

=> 7x=28

=> Therefore x=4

Comment: is this correct,i even posted it but no one replied .I wanted to know if i did it correctly

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It simply means that $x+11$ divides the numerator, i.e. $-11$  is a root of the numerator, the other root being $4/3$.  Use Vieta's relations to determine $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice $x^2-121=(x+11)(x-11)$. Then we have
$$
3x^2+kx-44=(3x-4)(x+11)=3x^2+29x-44.
$$
So $k=29$